# Партицирование mysql

Tags: mysql, yii2, partition

Подскажите пожалуйста по партицированию. Есть mysql таблица около 4 млн. записей. Выборка по полям id, country_id, city_id, apartment_id, date, adult, child, day. По всем необходимым полям индексы. Для фильтров (по стране, городам, количеству взрослых и детей) информация берется из отдельных таблиц, работает быстро.
Фильтр по дате - календарь для которого выбираются доступные даты в зависимости от выбранных ранее параметров фильтров. Для каждой доступной даты выбирается минимальная стоимость предложения на эту дату - работает очень медленно. Выборка по фильтрам тоже очень медленная, особенно запрос для получения количества всех записей для расчета страниц пагинации. Таблицу с предложениями разбил на партиции по country_id. Но, вроде как, стало еще хуже. Предложения получаю по крону, тогда сервер вообще падает.
Сайт на Yii2.

Comment: Партиционирование - совершенно не помощник в фасетном поиске.

Comment: Мой взгляд зацепился за пагинацию. Я так понимаю, с учётом фразы "_получения количества всех записей для расчета страниц_" вы используете limit-offset, что неэффективно. Используйте keyset pagination с `where id` - это намного быстрее. Правда, это не даёт выбирать произвольную страницу.

Comment: Возможность выбирать нужную страницу должна быть

Comment: Что можно придумать для ускорения поиска?